# Cursor: pointer is not working properly

Tags: html, css

I have developed a type-form where for cursor:pointer is not working.

```css
.confirm {
    position: absolute;
    padding: 10px;
  background-color: rgba(185, 208, 224, 0.26);
    border-radius: 3px;
    border-color: #828c94;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-style: solid;
 cursor:pointer;
}
.confirm .child1 {
    float: left;
    margin-left: 5px;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    background-color: #2C3F54;
    color: white;
    cursor:pointer;
}

.confirm .child2 {
    float: right;
    margin-left: 10px   ;
    padding: 15px;
 cursor:poniter;
}
```

```html
<div class="confirm" > <span class="button-wrapper child1"> <div class="button nav enabled "><span style="vertical-align:top">Ok </span><i class="material-icons">done</i> </div> </span> <span class="text child2">press <strong>ENTER</strong></span> </div>
```

cursor button is working only for top part but it is not working in bottom part

Comment: It's not poniter, it's pointer. (Last line)

Comment: What do you mean by 'bottom part'? It works well for me. While the cursor is over the button, it changes into the pointer.

Comment: Does anyone else derive wry amusement from the fact the title is misspelled as "curson:pointer is not working properly" and the problem with the code is `"cursor:poniter;"`?

Comment: @K.Daniek when you move cursor to the bottom side the pointer is not working

Comment: Yeah, kinda iritating.

Comment: @enhzflep still i am facing same issue.

Comment: @K.Daniek do you know how to solve this ?

Comment: You mean the bottom part of the button?

Comment: @K.Daniek yes !

Comment: I just don't know mate. It works fine for me. When I run the snippet, the pointer appears on the whole button.

Comment: @ArpitGupta - what's not working? The example in your question demonstrates no problem. Please, edit your question to include a working (i.e broken) button. Currently, your question appears useless and unanswerable I'm afraid. - Yes, there is the spelling error, but a different selector ensures that element gets the correct cursor anyway. The order of rules in the css is important in some cases,perhaps this is one?

Comment: Which browser do you use?

Answer (score 0):

I see the problem. In the selector `.confirm .child2` the pointer is misspelled. It should be `cursor: pointer`.

Comment: still i am facing this issue

Comment: @ArpitGupta Idk. Maybe change the z-index. Maybe that will work

Comment: We don't post answers for typo's, we comment and/or vote/flag for close as a typo.

Comment: @LGSon It's still an answer. Isn't it?

Comment: Yes, didn't say it wasn't, simply explained to you the SO policy for typo's, that as a specific close option which says _This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a **simple typographical error**. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem before posting._